# Query Regarding Account Data Skew

Tags: account, contact, data

We are facing an issue in Accounts. Sometimes we are getting an error like 'Unable to lock row' while saving/updating data. Is it related to Account Data Skew issue? But in our org, no Account has more than 10000 child records.

What may be the possible cause and solution to this? Please suggest.

Comment: Do you have lookups to some kind of reference / dictionary-like object on account? I'd expect it to be around M-D and not lookup relations but... Or do you maybe have triggers that roll "sum of account" up to that lookup object?